# Interpreting completion of a module as a Taylor expansion

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

An exercise in Atiyah-Macdonald asks the reader to show that if $A$ is a Noetherian ring, $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A$, and $M$ is a finitely-generated $A$-mdoule, then $$\hat{M} = 0 \iff \operatorname{Supp}(M) \cap \operatorname{V}(\mathfrak{a}) = \emptyset.$$
The authors then state:

> The reader should think of $\hat{M}$ as the "Taylor expansion" of $M$ transversal to the subscheme $\operatorname{V}(\mathfrak{a})$: the above result then shows that $M$ is determined in a neighborhood of $\operatorname{V}(\mathfrak{a})$ by its Taylor expansion.

I am completely befuddled by the block quote. Specifically:

1. What does it mean to have a Taylor expansion "transversal to [a] subscheme"?
2. How is this result related to $M$ being determined in a neighborhood of $\operatorname{V}(\mathfrak{a})$ by its Taylor expansion?